# Error Running Multiple Jobs In APScheduler "apscheduler.schedulers.SchedulerAlreadyRunningError: Scheduler is already running"

Tags: python-3.x, apscheduler

I'm trying to run multiple jobs in APScheduler and then delete them later. However, running the code below gives me this error, "apscheduler.schedulers.SchedulerAlreadyRunningError: Scheduler is already running."

```
from flask import Flask
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import time


sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
def settingJobs(number):
    global sched
    theId = "id"+number
    print("hello?")
    sched.add_job(deletingJobs, 'interval', args=[theId], seconds=5, id=theId)
    sched.start()

def deletingJobs(theId):
    print("Testing")
    sched.remove_job(theId)


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    for x in range(0,5):
        settingJobs(str(x))
        time.sleep(2)

    return "hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False, use_reloader=False)
```

The output I get is shown below

```
hello?
hello?
…
…
…
apscheduler.schedulers.SchedulerAlreadyRunningError: Scheduler is already running
```

If anyone could give me guidance on how to fix this or how to run multiple jobs and delete
them later, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Why so silent! the samae problem.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sched.start(), you must first check the scheduler's state. If it's already started, then don't start it again.

like this ,

```
if scheduler.state == 0 :
        scheduler.start()
```

Kindly check the [documentation](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/modules/schedulers/base.html?highlight=state#apscheduler.schedulers.base.STATE_STOPPED) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using flask-apscheduler and running tests, but FLASK_DEBUG env variable was set to False. I'm not sure I understand why, but setting the variable to True solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this too, but turns out it's very simple indeed.

When working with APScheduler, you must define a scheduler object as you've done:

```
sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
```

and start it in order to start **verifying your internal job list**. So if a job is added to this job list, this job will be scheduled, and if the job is removed it won't be scheduled anymore.
So this is the code refactored with this idea:

```
from flask import Flask
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import time


sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.start() # notice that the "start to watch" process happen here

def settingJobs(number):
    global sched
    theId = "id"+number
    print("hello?")
    sched.add_job(deletingJobs, 'interval', args=[theId], seconds=5, id=theId)

def deletingJobs(theId):
    print("Testing")
    sched.remove_job(theId)


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    for x in range(0,5):
        settingJobs(str(x))
        time.sleep(2)

    return "hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=False, use_reloader=False)
```

*Obs.:* The error raises because, you already had started that scheduler object once in the first loop iteration, so in the second iteration, Python try to restart a "non-stopped" scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Lukasavicus is right, in short, this line is the problem:

```
sched.start()
```

When you add a job or remove a job you're not stopping the scheduler and the scheduler is still running when you call this method again. You should move it elsewhere.